# submit a form with delphi

Tags: forms, delphi, browser, submit

I try to submit a prefilled form with Delphi - but it seems impossible. The Website I prefill is: [Lufthansa.com advanced search page](http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/de/booking?l=en&cid=18002)

I can't click on the "Find Flights" button:

```
<button type="submit" class="processBtn">
  <span class="stageButtonLeft">&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="stageButtonRight">Find flights</span>
</button>
```

or submit its form:

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off" 
  action="/booking/validation/flightavailability" 
  id="advancedSearchFlights">
```

I tried several things:

```
ie.OleObject.Document.forms.item(2).elements.item(0).click;
```

or

```
ie.OleObject.Document.forms.item(2).elements.item('submit').click;
```

or

```
 Frm := Doc3.getElementById('advancedSearchFlights') as IHtmlFormElement;
 if Assigned(Frm) then
  Frm.submit;
```

Nothing ever happens. How is it possible to submit this form via Delphi ?

Comment: Try doing some debugging. Where does the code fail?

Comment: I would do a POST request to the site instead.

Comment: "Find flights" is itself not a button, but a `span` on top of a button.  What are you actually trying to "click" on - the button or the span? You did not show the full HTML of the form, so we cannot see the parent/child relationships of the various elements.  Also, to submit a form, don't "click" on the form's submit button, call the `submit()` method of the `form` object itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the form event using chrome to get the right parameters and use Indy to post the form.

Something like this...

```
var
  objHttp: TIdHttp;
  objPostResponse: TMemoryStream;
  objParamPost: TStringList;
begin
    objHttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
        objHttp.HandleRedirects := True;
        objHttp.AllowCookies := True;
        objHttp.Get('http://www....');
        objPostResponse := TMemoryStream.Create;
        try
            objParametrosPost := TStringList.Create;
            try
                objParamPost.Add('hdnStatus=ativo');                    
                objHttp.Post('http://www...', objParamPost, objPostResponse);
            finally
                FreeAndNil(objParamPost);
            end;
            // do whatever you want with the response
        finally
          FreeAndNil(objPostResponse);
        end;
    finally
        FreeAndNil(objHttp);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: `TIdHTTP.Create(nil)` can be shortened to `TIdHTTP.Create`